# Setting up gstreamer pipeline in Python

Tags: python, gstreamer

I have a `Gstreamer` pipeline that works when launched with `gst-launch`, but I cannot get it to work in a python script.

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src do-timestamp=true device=/dev/video0 ! image/jpeg,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! nvv4l2decoder mjpeg=1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! clockoverlay halignment=left valignment=bottom text="Dashcam" shaded-background=true font-desc="Sans, 12" ! omxh264enc ! 'video/x-h264, streamformat=(string)byte-stream' ! h264parse ! qtmux ! filesink location=video.mp4
```

I've tried using `gst-parse` on everything after `gst-launch`, tried subprocess.popen, and cannot figure out head or tails of the gstreamer element factory. Any tips?

Things I've tried:

```
import subprocess

dashcam = 'gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src do-timestamp=true device=/dev/video0 ! image/jpeg,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! nvv4l2decoder mjpeg=1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! clockoverlay halignment=left valignment=bottom text="Dashcam" shaded-background=true font-desc="Sans, 12" ! omxh264enc ! "video/x-h264, streamformat=(string)byte-stream" ! h264parse ! qtmux ! filesink location=video.mp4 -e'
dashcamPipe = subprocess.Popen(dashcam.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = dashcamPipe.communicate()
```

Gives me these errors

```
gst-launch-1.0:18562): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 07:47:51.920: gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:18562): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 07:47:51.927: gst_element_link_pads_filtered: assertion 'GST_IS_BIN (parent)' failed
```

Using Gst.parse_launch

```
import gi 
import sys
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject

Gst.init(sys.argv)

pipeline = Gst.parse_launch('v4l2src do-timestamp=true device=/dev/video0 ! image/jpeg,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! nvv4l2decoder mjpeg=1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! clockoverlay halignment=left valignment=bottom text="Dashcam" shaded-background=true font-desc="Sans, 12" ! omxh264enc ! "video/x-h264, streamformat=(string)byte-stream" ! h264parse ! ! qtmux ! filesink location=video.mp4
```

Gives me

```
(record.py:18791): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 07:53:00.456: gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed

(record.py:18791): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 07:53:00.463: gst_element_link_pads_filtered: assertion 'GST_IS_BIN (parent)' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "record.py", line 8, in <module>
    pipeline = Gst.parse_launch('v4l2src do-timestamp=true device=/dev/video0 ! image/jpeg,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! nvv4l2decoder mjpeg=1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! clockoverlay halignment=left valignment=bottom text="Dashcam" shaded-background=true font-desc="Sans, 12" ! omxh264enc ! "video/x-h264, streamformat=(string)byte-stream" ! h264parse ! qtmux ! filesink location=video.mp4')
GLib.Error: gst_parse_error: syntax error (0)
```

Comment: where is your script?

Comment: you split problem into smaller items and you could start with `parse_launch('v4l2src')` to see if it has problem with `gst_parse_error`, next you could try with `parse_launch('v4l2src do-timestamp=true')`, etc. until you get minimal path which makes problem and it you will know which element can make problem.

Comment: I tested your code this way and I found that problem makes `" "` in element `! "video/x-h264, streamformat=(string)byte-stream" !`. If I use `! video/x-h264, streamformat=(string)byte-stream !` then it has no problem with parsing.

Answer (score 1):

[Furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas) nailed it in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69441058/setting-up-gstreamer-pipeline-in-python/69451580#comment122755492_69441058). It was the `" "` in the main pipeline element causing all the issues. Taking them out fixes it for both `popen` and the parse.

New (and updated) code:

```
import gi 
import sys
from time import sleep

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject

Gst.init(sys.argv)

pipeline = Gst.parse_launch('v4l2src do-timestamp=true device=/dev/video0 ! image/jpeg,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! nvv4l2decoder mjpeg=1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! clockoverlay halignment=left valignment=bottom text="Dashcam" shaded-background=true font-desc="Sans, 12" ! omxh264enc ! "video/x-h264, streamformat=(string)byte-stream" ! h264parse ! ! qtmux ! filesink location=video.mp4')

def main():
  bus = pipeline.get_bus()      
  pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
  print('Recording Dashcam')
  
  sleep(10) 
  print('Sending EOS')
  pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())
  print('Waiting for EOS')
  bus.timed_pop_filtered(Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE, Gst.MessageType.EOS)
  pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

main()
```

This starts a recording, waits ten seconds, then ends it gracefully if anyone else needs it.

Comment: Question on coding style, doesn't the "main" function executed two times?